# As a Self Employed LLC filer living in NYC. How can I estimate my taxes? Is there a Tax filing form simulator I can input numbers into?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, self-employment, state-income-tax, form-1040

I have the following example values of:

- Self Employed LLC Income: 50K (Computer Repair Business)
- Married filing jointly
- 2 children
- No mortgage or property. We rent.
- Paying for daycare - $800/month.
- No investments

---

- Is there a tax form simulator to estimate my taxes to get a rough idea of what I can deduct and owe?
- What forms are required from the given values above? I just know about 1040.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a tax 1040 simulator: https://www.jacksonhewitt.com/tax-tools/tax-refund-calculators/1040-tax-calculator/ -- There is actually quite a number of them if you google for "1040 Tax Simulator"

The main points to know about for filing taxes is the following from my research thus far:

- **Know the difference from a deduction and a tax credit.** A deduction reduces your taxable income. Example: You make 100K and deduction is 10K. You get taxed on 90K only. A tax credit is to reduce your TAX amount. Example: Ignore how much you make. You owe 9K in taxes, your tax credit is 1K. You pay 8K in taxes.
- **Total income** means before Adjusted Gross Income (AGI). AGI is your Total Income **MINUS** all the **Adjustments to Income** category on **Schedule 1**. See below:

[image]

- Understand the basic **Standard deductions**. Married you get to "deduct" 24K from your income. Thereby reducing your taxable income.

[image]

- Self Employment Tax (**Form Schedule SE**) you always get 50% off of it. See below:

[image]